# Iterate over a list of values within a Hashmap

Tags: java, data-structures, lexical-analysis

Lexical Analysis program: with a text file, segregate each token under categories such as keyword, characters, digits, integers.

So I created a hashMap where Each key in the hash map have to be segregated in a way that i.e Keyword = [if, then, else], Special = [(,),.,;], Character = [a,b,c], *so each key has it's own list.*

But I also need to count the number of times each token appears within the text file, so I was thinking of iterating through each separate list and finding the occurrences of each word/character/digit there, however it's definitely a lot of bad code because I can't think of a way that's better than if list.contains(word) count++, and doing that for every single word/character/digit.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    private static HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map;
    private static ArrayList<String> keys;
    private static ArrayList<String> special;
    private static ArrayList<String> characters;
    private static ArrayList<String> integers;
    private static ArrayList<String> digits;
    private static Token k;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        map = new HashMap<>();
        keys = new ArrayList<>();
        special = new ArrayList<>();
        characters = new ArrayList<>();
        integers = new ArrayList<>();
        digits = new ArrayList<>();
        k = new Token();

        executeAnalysis();
    }

    private static void executeAnalysis() {
        try {
            File file = new File("/Users/karinaabad/Desktop/HW311.txt");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

            while(scanner.hasNext()) {
                String w = scanner.next();
                segregateTokens(w);
            }
            printSummary();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException f) {
            System.out.println("Invalid file input.");
        }
    }

    private static void segregateTokens(String w) {
        if (k.checkKeyword(w))
        {
            keys.add(w);
        }

        if (k.checkSpecial(w)) {
            special.add(w);
        }

        if (k.checkDigit(w)) {
            digits.add(w);
        }

        if (k.checkIntegers(w)) {
            integers.add(w);
        }

        if (k.checkCharacters(w)) {
            characters.add(w);
        }

        map.put("Keyword", keys);
        map.put("Special", special);
        map.put("Digit", digits);
        map.put("Integers", integers);
        map.put("Characters", characters);
    }

    private static void printSummary() {
        System.out.println("==========Summary Report==========");
        for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> pair : map.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " : " + pair.getValue());
        }
    }

    private static void checkCount() {
        for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> key : map.entrySet()) {
            for (String value : )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It prints a newline, so that everything isn't printed on one line.

Comment: [`PrintStream#println()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println())

Answer (score 0):

The `println()` call prints a newline after the loop has completed (at the end of the line containing the integers).

If the `println()` was not there and the code were to try to print something else, it would appear on the same line as the integers.